# Language not changing in Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I set this form to allow me to change the language of the App from any view. Somehow (can't find out why) when I access my registration view (implemented with Devise) I'm not allowed to change it, also If i go back to the previous view or any other I can no longer switch between any language.

**Application.html.slim**

```
- idiomas = options_for_select(User.language_list)
.btn.btn-raised.btn-icon.btn icon_language.margin_medium_right.align_items_center
form id="language_selector" method = "GET"
= select_tag(:locale, idiomas, prompt: t('language'), class: 'btn_select')

jQuery('#locale').on('change',function(){
  jQuery('#language_selector').submit();
});
```

**Application_controller.rb**

```
def set_locale
    choosen_locale = params[:locale] if params[:locale] &&  
    I18n.available_locales.include?(params[:locale].to_sym)
    I18n.locale = choosen_locale || I18n.default_locale
end

def default_url_options
    { locale: I18n.locale }
end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /es|en/ do
resources :ajax
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations', sessions: 'sessions' }
devise_for :unregisters,
  class_name: 'User',
  only: [],
  controllers: { registrations: 'unregisters' }

devise_scope :unregister do
  get   "/unregisters/new", to: "unregisters#new", as: :new_unregister
  post  "/unregisters",    to: "unregisters#create", as: :unregisters
end

namespace 'admin' do
  resources :clinics, except: %i[new create destroy], constraints: { id: /\d+/ }
  resources :doctors, except: %i[new create destroy], constraints: { id: /\d+/ }
  resources :specializations, except: %i[new create destroy], constraints: { id: /\d+/ }
  resources :treatments, except: %i[new create destroy], constraints: { id: /\d+/ }
  resources :insurance_contracts, except: %i[new create destroy], constraints: { id: /\d+/ }
  resources :external_contents, only: %i[index edit update], constraints: { id: /\d+/ }
  resources :signed_up_users, only: %i[index edit update show destroy], constraints: { id: /\d+/ }
end

resources :appointment_steps
resources :appointments, only: %i[index]
delete 'appointment/:code', to: 'appointments#destroy', as: 'destroy_appointment'

resources :appointment_payments, only: %i[create]
resources :availabilities, only: %i[index]
resources :clinics, only: :index
resources :clinic_history, only: :index
get 'download_external_file/:document_external_id', to: 'clinic_history#download_external_file', as: 'download_external_file'

resources :clinic_documents, only: :index
resources :doctors, only: :index
resources :insurance_cards
resources :treatments, only: :index
resource :insurance_payments, only: %i[create show]

resource :passwords
root to: 'home#index'
end
```

Feel free to ask for any more details if you have a slight idea of what's going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake. 
The error is located in my routes.rb 
It should look like this.
It seems that the scope does not work well with devise_for and devise_scope

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations', sessions: 'sessions' }
devise_for :unregisters,
  class_name: 'User',
  only: [],
  controllers: { registrations: 'unregisters' }

devise_scope :unregister do
  get   "/unregisters/new", to: "unregisters#new", as: :new_unregister
  post  "/unregisters",    to: "unregisters#create", as: :unregisters
end

scope "(:locale)", locale: /es|en/ do
resources :ajax

namespace 'admin' do
  resources :clinics, except: %i[new create destroy], constraints: { id: /\d+/ }
  resources :doctors, except: %i[new create destroy], constraints: { id: /\d+/ }
  resources :specializations, except: %i[new create destroy], constraints: { id: /\d+/ }
  resources :treatments, except: %i[new create destroy], constraints: { id: /\d+/ }
  resources :insurance_contracts, except: %i[new create destroy], constraints: { id: /\d+/ }
  resources :external_contents, only: %i[index edit update], constraints: { id: /\d+/ }
  resources :signed_up_users, only: %i[index edit update show destroy], constraints: { id: /\d+/ }
end

resources :appointment_steps
resources :appointments, only: %i[index]
delete 'appointment/:code', to: 'appointments#destroy', as: 'destroy_appointment'

resources :appointment_payments, only: %i[create]
resources :availabilities, only: %i[index]
resources :clinics, only: :index
resources :clinic_history, only: :index
get 'download_external_file/:document_external_id', to: 'clinic_history#download_external_file', as: 'download_external_file'

resources :clinic_documents, only: :index
resources :doctors, only: :index
resources :insurance_cards
resources :treatments, only: :index
resource :insurance_payments, only: %i[create show]

resource :passwords
root to: 'home#index'
end
```